# How to create String primary Key in lift's Mapper ORM?

Tags: lift, mapper

How can we create a mapper with string as it's primary key in lift's Mapper ORM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge this should work..

```
class StringCodes extends KeyedMapper[String,StringCodes] {

  def getSingleton = StringCodes
  def primaryKeyField = languageCd

  object strCd extends MappedStringIndex(this,5)
  {
    override def writePermission_? = true   // if u want to set it via your code, keep this true
    override def dbAutogenerated_? = false
    override def dbNotNull_? = true
    override def dbColumnName="str_cd"
  }

....
```

Answer (score 0):

From Lift documentation [here](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Mapper):

> Naturally Mapper also supports String primary keys, though your model class and companion object will need to mixin different traits and you’ll need to have a MappedStringIndex field.