# How does one replace the trait IdPK with a custom trait that uses a String Primary Key instead of Long Primary Key?

Tags: scala, lift, traits

Yet another trait question :-(

I am mixing in the IdPK trait into my Lift Mapper models as follows:

```
class Test1 extends LongKeyedMapper[Test1] with IdPK {
```

I would like to switch to using String indexes instead of Long indexes (I don't want to but I have to, for now). I am trying to write a trait `StringIdPK` to replace the `IdPK` trait. Here is my attempt:

```
trait StringIdPK /* extends BaseLongKeyedMapper */ {  
  self: KeyedMapper[String] =>  
  def primaryKeyField = id  
  object id extends MappedStringIndex(this, 50)  
}
```

(I based this on the `IdPK` trait which is as follows:

```
trait IdPK /* extends BaseLongKeyedMapper */ {  
  self: BaseLongKeyedMapper =>  
  def primaryKeyField = id  
  object id extends MappedLongIndex[MapperType](this.asInstanceOf[MapperType])  
}
```

the code for this trait can be found [here](http://main.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.1/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/mapper/Mapper.scala.html#Some(318)))

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
wrong number of type arguments for net.liftweb.mapper.KeyedMapper, should be 2
```

The specification for `KeyedMapper` (which can be found [here](http://liftweb.net/api/26/api/index.html#net.liftweb.mapper.KeyedMapper)) is:

```
trait KeyedMapper[KeyType, OwnerType <: KeyedMapper[KeyType, OwnerType]] extends Mapper[OwnerType] with BaseKeyedMapper
```

I need to better understand what `OwnerType <: KeyedMapper[KeyType, OwnerType]` means and how to accommodate it in my custom trait above. So my question is: what am I doing wrong in my definition of the trait `StringIdPK` above? (This will help me to understand how to deal with `OwnerType <: KeyedMapper[KeyType, OwnerType]`).

Thanks!

UPDATE: I think the following comes close to solving it (see below - I took some of the code from [here](https://code.google.com/p/ding-forum/source/browse/ding-forum/src/main/scala/com/ding/model/StringKeyedMapper.scala?spec=svn9&r=9)). It is still not quite right, since the compiler still complains about the FK objects I extended not having foreign meta defined.

```
trait BaseStringKeyedMapper extends BaseKeyedMapper{
    override type TheKeyType = String
}

trait StringKeyedMapper[OwnerType <: StringKeyedMapper[OwnerType]] extends KeyedMapper[String, OwnerType] with BaseStringKeyedMapper {
    self: OwnerType =>
}


trait StringKeyedMetaMapper[A <: StringKeyedMapper[A]] extends KeyedMetaMapper[String, A] {
    self: A =>
}

trait StringIdPK {  
  self: BaseStringKeyedMapper =>  
  def primaryKeyField = id  
  object id extends MappedStringIndex[MapperType](this.asInstanceOf[MapperType], 50)  
}
```

Also, there was a posting about this issue [on the lift google group here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/DbmLczdRuxc), but it seems unresolved.

Comment: What's exactly the problem? I have just compiled and used this code to create a Mapper model using StringKeyedMapper.

Comment: @Andre Luiz, thanks for your comment. I checked again, and it works now. I think the problem I had earlier was with adding an owner field and mapping this as a foreign key of User, which I still cannot get to have a string PK. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following solves it (I'm unable to confirm right now because I am working through another issue before I can really test it, but this seems to work so far. I took some of the code from [here](https://code.google.com/p/ding-forum/source/browse/ding-forum/src/main/scala/com/ding/model/StringKeyedMapper.scala?spec=svn9&r=9) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416161/how-to-create-string-primary-key-in-lifts-mapper-orm). I will update this as I learn more about this implementation):

```
trait BaseStringKeyedMapper extends BaseKeyedMapper{
    override type TheKeyType = String
}

trait StringKeyedMapper[OwnerType <: StringKeyedMapper[OwnerType]] extends KeyedMapper[String, OwnerType] with BaseStringKeyedMapper {
    self: OwnerType =>
}

trait StringKeyedMetaMapper[A <: StringKeyedMapper[A]] extends KeyedMetaMapper[String, A] {
    self: A =>
}

trait StringIdPK {  
  self: BaseStringKeyedMapper =>  
  def primaryKeyField = id  
  object id extends MappedStringIndex[MapperType](this.asInstanceOf[MapperType], 50) {
      override def writePermission_? = true // if u want to set it via your code, keep this true
      override def dbAutogenerated_? = false
      override def dbNotNull_? = true

      // override def writePermission_? = false
      override def readPermission_? = true
      override def shouldDisplay_? = true
      override def show_? = true
      override def dbDisplay_? = true
      override def validations = valUnique(S.?("Must be unique")) _ :: super.validations
  }
}
```

I've added some overrides to the `id` field for mixing this in along with CRUDify. For some reason that I cannot figure out, `valUnique` does not work (other validations such as `valMinLen` do work, however). I will post a new question about this.